# Вопрос по поводу логики исполнения кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function openSubMenu() {

    $('.work-examples__li').each(function () {
        testingByNik();
    });

    function testingByNik() {
        $(this).on("click", function () {

            //var tarGet = $(".work-examples .example.view-project-first");
            //var activeBlock = $(".first .work-examples__li_active");

            var tarGet = $(this).find(".example");
            var activeBlock = $(this).find(".work-examples__li_active");


            $(".projects__content .work-examples .example:not('.view-project-first')").removeClass("pop-up");
            $(".projects__content .work-examples .work-examples__li_active:not('.first')").removeClass("visible");

            if (!tarGet.hasClass('pop-up') && !activeBlock.hasClass('visible')) {
                tarGet.addClass('pop-up');
                activeBlock.addClass('visible');
            } else {
                tarGet.removeClass('pop-up');
                activeBlock.removeClass('visible');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

И так, для каждого `.work-examples__li` я выполняю функцию `testingByNik`
Эта функция выполняется, когда я кликаю по `.work-examples__li`. Дальше `tarGet` - это `.work_examples__li .example`, a `.activeBlock` это `.work-examples__li .work-examples__li_active.`
Так ведь?

Comment: Судя по коду вы исполняете `testingByNik` не для каждого `.work-examples__li`, а просто столько раз. Потому что никак не связываете вызов функции и найденные элементы.

Comment: `$('.work-examples__li').each(testingByNik)`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, твой вариант заработал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Эта функция выполняется, когда я кликаю ...

Нет, эта функция выполняется, когда Вы ее вызываете. По щелчку выполняется обработчик события `click` - анонимная функция в

```
$(this).on("click", function () {
  ...
});
```

Судя по коду внутри `testingByNik`, Вы ожидаете, что контекстом для нее будет один из элементов `'.work-examples__li'`. В Вашем коде это не так - Вы вызываете ее в глобальном контексте `window`.

Можно сделать вот так:

```
$('.work-examples__li').each(function () {
  testingByNik.call(this);
});
```

Но в Вашем цикле нет никакой необходимости. Для всех выбранных элементов Вы делаете  одно и то же.

```
$('.work-examples__li').on("click", function () {

    //var tarGet = $(".work-examples .example.view-project-first");
    //var activeBlock = $(".first .work-examples__li_active");

    var tarGet = $(this).find(".example");
    var activeBlock = $(this).find(".work-examples__li_active");

    $(".projects__content .work-examples .example:not('.view-project-first')").removeClass("pop-up");
    $(".projects__content .work-examples .work-examples__li_active:not('.first')").removeClass("visible");

    if (!tarGet.hasClass('pop-up') && !activeBlock.hasClass('visible')) {
        tarGet.addClass('pop-up');
        activeBlock.addClass('visible');
    } else {
        tarGet.removeClass('pop-up');
        activeBlock.removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня девять блоков .work-examples__li и нужно при клике делать обработчик только тому, на кого я нажал. Вот в чем идея